# Why is my R script using all the computer's memory?

Tags: r, memory, docx, qdap

I wrote a simple script which opens each .docx document from my folders and looks for certain words. If any of the words exist, it extracts an ID number and then moves on to the next document. The problem is that after ~1500 documents, it consumes all the computer's memory and R gets stuck and aborts. I don't know why it happens - my script should not be using so much memory. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

```
rm(list=ls()) #clean environment
library(qdapTools)
setwd("C:/DocxArchive/ParentFolder")
results <- 0 #store results here
years_list <- c("2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020")

for (year_index in 1:11) {
  parent_dir <- years_list[year_index]     
  file_list <- list.files(path = parent_dir, recursive = TRUE) #get list of file names
  items_to_delete <- grep('~',file_list) #find temporary files - name begins with '~'
  file_list <- file_list[-items_to_delete] #delete temporary files from file list
  length_of_file_list <- length(file_list)
  file_num <- 1 #initialize file number index
  while(file_num <= length_of_file_list){ 
    DOCX <- read_docx(file=file.path(parent_dir, file_list[file_num]))
      index_of_HITEC1 <- grepl("HI TEC", DOCX, fixed=FALSE, ignore.case=TRUE) 
      index_of_HITEC2 <- grepl("HITEC", DOCX, fixed=FALSE, ignore.case=TRUE) 
      index_of_HITEC3 <- grepl("HI-TEC", DOCX, fixed=FALSE, ignore.case=TRUE) 
      HITEC1_num <- which.max(index_of_HITEC1) #line in document where word exists
      HITEC2_num <- which.max(index_of_HITEC2) #line in document where word exists
      HITEC3_num <- which.max(index_of_HITEC3) #line in document where word exists
      HITEC_sum <- HITEC1_num+HITEC2_num+HITEC3_num
      if (HITEC_sum > 3){
        index_of_person_ID <- grepl("ID:", DOCX, fixed=TRUE) #find lines where ID exist
        text <- DOCX[index_of_person_ID==TRUE] #keep only lines where ID exist
        text <- gsub("[^0-9]","",text) #delete everything except numbers
        results <- c(results,text)
      } #end of if loop
      file_num <- file_num+1
   } #end of while loop 
} #end of for loop
```

Comment: On a first glance I only see `results` as a candidate for increasing memory usage. Can you print/ cat the (in memory) size of `results` while the script is running?

Comment: Thank you! using `print(object.size(results))`, I see that the memory usage is very small (140 bytes) and does not increase if new data is not added to the vector.

Comment: I don't think this represents the actual in memory size... 140 bytes is way to small. Maybe you get a better answer using `pryr::object_size()` (See [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html) for more information on what R returns with its builtin `object_size`)

Comment: The vector is almost empty, so 140 bytes makes sense. It is very rare to find a document with data that should be entered into the 'results' vector.

Comment: You could use a tool like `provis` [source](https://github.com/rstudio/profvis) to inspect your code and visualize memory usage...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: the memory leak was the fault of `qdapTools::read_docx`. Using `officer::read_docx`, there is no problem.

Answer (score 3):

> We made our way into the second Circle, here live the gluttons.

It might help you to read a bit of [R inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf#page=13). Aside from a possible memory leak arising from `read_docx`, the line that jumps out to me as problematic is:

```r
results <- c(results, text)
```

There are some details in R Inferno Ch. 2, but basically when you do this, you incur a full copy of `results` from its old place in memory to a new one, and this happens in every single loop iteration. This means that most of the time you will be using almost double the memory you need to, and possibly much more, since R's garbage collector generally only frees memory when it is requested.

You could improve this code by using a programming different pattern to save the results or, if you are feeling very lazy, by calling `gc()` periodically (say, every 10th iteration of the loop).

Comment: Thank you! using print(object.size(results)), I see that the memory usage is very small (140 bytes) and does not increase if new data is not added to the vector.

Comment: What do you see if you run `sapply(ls(), function(x) format(object.size(get(x)), units="auto"))`?

Comment: If you're scanning through 1,000 files, I don't see how you're only getting 140 bytes of results. `object.size("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")` is 152 bytes.

Comment: When I run `sapply(ls(), function(x) format(object.size(get(x)), units="auto"))`, no variable is gaining memory size with iterations, they all remain very well behaved. I guess it must be the `read_docx`..?

Comment: I don't think so. If I run `read_docx` thousands of times, the memory usage doesn't increase.

Comment: Even with `gc(full=TRUE)`, memory consumption keeps rising.